# rollapplyr students t-test across columns

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like:

```
   group date         Mal   Fem
   <chr> <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 grp1  2020-07-01     7     5
 2 grp1  2020-07-02    17    17
 3 grp1  2020-07-03    16    15
 4 grp1  2020-07-04     6     9
 5 grp1  2020-07-05     6     3
```

Which has 3 groups `grp1`, `grp2` and `grp3`. I want to see how their distributions have changed over time and I thought it would be interesting to plot a "grouped rolling t-test", with a lag period of 7 days for example.

I do the following:

```
# Process and convert data to a zoo object
df_ts <- df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = c(Mal, Fem)) %>% 
  select(date, contains("grp1")) %>% 
  timetk::tk_zoo()

# Define a t test function
ttestFun <- function(dat) {
  myTtest = t.test(x = dat[, 1], y = dat[, 2])
  return(myTtest)
}

# See if the t test functionw works
ttestFun(df_ts)

# Apply the function to the rolling data
rollapplyr(df_ts, 7, FUN = ttestFun, fill = NA, by.column = FALSE)
```

I am trying to do 2 things.

1. Get the code working for the rolling window since at the moment it breaks on the `rollapplyr` function with the following error:

> Error in zoo(rval, index(x)[i]) :    “x” : attempt to define invalid
> zoo object

2. Get the code to not only apply the t test to (`grp1` and `grp2`) but also the other combinations (`grp1` and `grp3`) and (`grp2` and `grp3`)

Data:

```
    df <- structure(list(group = c("grp1", "grp1", "grp1", "grp1", "grp1", 
"grp1", "grp1", "grp1", "grp1", "grp1", "grp1", "grp1", "grp1", 
"grp1", "grp1", "grp2", "grp2", "grp2", "grp2", "grp2", "grp2", 
"grp2", "grp2", "grp2", "grp2", "grp2", "grp2", "grp2", "grp2", 
"grp2", "grp3", "grp3", "grp3", "grp3", "grp3", "grp3", "grp3", 
"grp3", "grp3", "grp3", "grp3", "grp3", "grp3", "grp3", "grp3"
), date = structure(c(18444, 18445, 18446, 18447, 18448, 18449, 
18450, 18451, 18452, 18453, 18454, 18455, 18456, 18457, 18458, 
18444, 18445, 18446, 18447, 18448, 18449, 18450, 18451, 18452, 
18453, 18454, 18455, 18456, 18457, 18458, 18444, 18445, 18446, 
18447, 18448, 18449, 18450, 18451, 18452, 18453, 18454, 18455, 
18456, 18457, 18458), class = "Date"), Mal = c(7, 17, 16, 6, 
6, 8, 20, 4, 20, 36, 13, 8, 19, 14, 19, 42, 31, 35, 29, 3, 23, 
39, 30, 25, 46, 30, 11, 47, 59, 55, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 
1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1), Fem = c(5, 17, 15, 9, 3, 10, 14, 12, 19, 41, 
6, 9, 21, 14, 18, 61, 36, 49, 46, 13, 24, 37, 39, 38, 56, 31, 
21, 53, 61, 65, 6, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 5, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-45L), groups = structure(list(group = c("grp1", "grp2", "grp3"
), .rows = structure(list(1:15, 16:30, 31:45), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be related to the structure of output of `t.test`.  It is a `list`.  If we extract the components i.e. `p.value` or `estimate` it would work

```
 ttestFun <- function(dat) {
   myTtest = t.test(x = dat[, 1], y = dat[, 2])
   return(myTtest$p.value)
 }
```

-testing

```
rollapply(df_ts, 7, FUN = ttestFun, fill = NA, by.column = FALSE)
#2020-07-01 2020-07-02 2020-07-03 2020-07-04 2020-07-05 2020-07-06 2020-07-07 2020-07-08 2020-07-09 2020-07-10 2020-07-11 
#        NA         NA         NA  0.7452034  0.8892572  0.9319528  0.8614528  0.9649029  0.9632735  0.9621904  0.8495438 
#2020-07-12 2020-07-13 2020-07-14 2020-07-15 
# 0.9795584         NA         NA         NA
```